# Starting the scroll to the bottom of a div tag

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I know its simple and easy to do but in my case i dont know why its not working,
I have div with scroll and i want it to start in bottom. I have read some question here and search in google but its not working into my program. this is my jquery code it start in bottom but when i scrolled it will always back in bottom.so i remove the the set interval and i just call the function `updateScroll();` but the scroll start in top again guys help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function updateScroll(){
  var element = document.getElementById("msgss");
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
 }
 setInterval(updateScroll,1000);

</script>
```

this is my div tag

```
<div class="col-md-6 convo">
  <chat-log :messages="messages" id="msgss"></chat-log>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 chat-composer">
      <textarea class="compose" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type your Message" v-model="messageText" @keydown="vmsg"></textarea>
      <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary send" @click="sendMessage">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the content of the `<chat-log :messages="messages" id="msgss"></chat-log>`

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="chat-log">
      <chat-message v-for="message in messages" v-bind:key="messages.text" :message="message"></chat-message>
      <div class="empty" v-show="messages.length === 0">
          Nothing here yet!
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the css

```
#msgss{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 540px;
}
```

Comment: not a laravel issue

Comment: okay. sorry sir

Comment: consider wrapping your call to updateScroll function inside `$(document).ready(function(){ updateScroll()}); Remove `setInterval(updateScroll,1000);`

Comment: i also do that sir its not working

Comment: instead of using `var element = document.getElementById("msgss");' , could you please try once                                                                   var element = document.querySelector("div.chat-log"); along with the document.ready changes suggested above.

Comment: same result nothing changes . not working, my script is working only with setInterval(updateScroll, 1000). but the issue with that is its keep going to the bottom i want is the user can freely scroll but it will begin in the bottom

Comment: instead of setInterval , you can use setTimeout maybe. setTimeout will trigger only once after a specified timeout unlike setInterval which keeps ticking.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this

```
 window.setInterval(function() {
      var element = document.getElementById('msgss');
      element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: can you provide exact source code that is rendering?

Comment: https://github.com/eduardotkoller/convForm look at this demo may be this can help you

Comment: my script is working only with setInterval(updateScroll, 1000). but the issue with that is its keep going to the bottom i want is the user can freely scroll but it will begin in the bottom

Comment: call setInterval(updateScroll, 1000) on click of send button as well it will scroll to the bottom after every message send

Comment: yes. but when i scroll it to the top after one second it going down to the bottom

Comment: Recently did something very similar. My solution was to check if the last message was visible before adding a new message. If it was, scroll to the bottom after adding a new message and if not don't scroll.

Comment: yah. but in my case i want it to start in bottom immediately and can freely scroll up and down